# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have the following HTML code:

```
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<link href='/static/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='/static/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='/static/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='/static/js/jquery/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>
<script src='/static/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {


        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    })

});
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function(index):18
```

Comment: Are you sure that you fullcalendar.min.js file is loaded correctly?

Comment: Include moment.min.js below jQuery reference

Comment: @Shaunak, I don't believe it's relevant, because momentjs doesn't have a jquery dependency as far as I know.

Comment: @ilter, I think it does loaded correctly since I checked in the inspect element.

Comment: The code you show looks correct.  Try making sure there is no other javascript on the page at all.

Comment: @Owlvark, thats all the javascript. I am using the django framework.

Comment: isn't django a server side framework? How is that related to a javascript error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would start simple by creating a simple "sample.html" page and only add what's needed to debug that particular problem (In your case, just jquery and fullcalendar scripts). Then add the rest of the scripts one by one and check by refreshing the browser in every step.

And, you might try moving your $(document).ready function at the bottom of the body (in order to make sure DOM is fully loaded before executing any script on the page).

Also, don't forget the ";" sign at the end of your lines, where needed. It can be painful when you minify or concatenate your javascript files on the production phase.

Hope that helps...

Comment: "@Yihao Cheng", can you tell us which part of my answer helped you? I had a few recommendations...